Firebase Auth session ends automatically when I close the application on my iOS device
I am developing a mobile application using Unity and I am using Firebase. I can register using Firebase Auth in my application. There is a problem. While trying the test versions of my application on Android devices, I can register using Firebase Auth. I close the application and when I open the application again, I remain logged in. However, when I close the application and reopen it on iOS devices, I do not remain logged in. It automatically logs me out and I have to log in again. Why am I having this problem?
What did I try to solve this problem?
I added keychain capability in xcode but it did not solve my problem.
I toggle off development mode

Welcome to SO. The issue is because of a bug in your code. However, without seeing your code and troubleshooting, we will be unable to assist. The best questions about code include  a brief example of the code you're having difficulty with. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Update your question and we'll take a look.
